# Test for list member positions

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, filtering

Let's say there is a list like: `l1={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}`
If you're given some arbitrary element and a distance, how do you find the of list elements that are that distance away from the element. 
For example get: `{1,7}`when the following is called: `[l1,4,3]`
I can't quit make the connection between position and the built it Nearest[] function. Would Nearest[] even be useful in this case or should I look at actual list operations?

Comment: What result do you expect for `[l1, 4, 4]`?

Comment: error because the left hand would fall out of the boundary of the list

Answer (score 4):

A quick thing. I'd just use normal list operations and keep it simple.

```
get[list_List, ele_, (dist_Integer)?Positive] := 
 Module[{p, res = {}, n},
  p = Flatten@Position[list, ele];
  Do[
   If[p[[n]] - dist >= 1,
    AppendTo[res, list[[p[[n]] - dist]]]
    ];
   If[p[[n]] + dist <= Length@list,
    AppendTo[res, list[[p[[n]] + dist]]]
    ]
   ,
   {n, 1, Length@p}
   ];
  res
  ]
```

Then

```
  get[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 4, 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  get[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 4, 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  get[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4}, 4, 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  get[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4}, 4, 7]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  get[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -5, 7, 8, 4}, -5, 3]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Bug reports are welcome and will be processed in the order they are received.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[g]
g[l_List, e_, d_Integer?Positive] := l[[Select[1 <= # <= Length[l] &]@
   Flatten @ Function[x, {d, -d} + x, Listable] @ Position[l, e]]]
```

Using Nasser's example inputs:

```
inputs = {{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 4, 3}, 
   {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},  4, 4},
   {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 4, 5}, 
   {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4}, 4, 3},
   {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4}, 4, 7}, 
   {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -5, 7, 8, 4}, -5, 3}};

g @@@ inputs
```

> ```
>   {{1, 7}, {8}, {}, {1, 7, 6}, {2}, {3, 4}}
> ```

```
Grid[Prepend[{##, g@##} & @@@ inputs, {"lst", "e", "d", "g[lst, e, d]"}], Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`SequenceCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html):

```
ClearAll[g2]
g2[l_List, e_, d_Integer?Positive] := SequenceCases[l,
    {a_, Repeated[_, {d - 1}], e} | {e, Repeated[_, {d - 1}], b_} :> Sequence[a, b], 
    Overlaps -> True];

g2 @@@ inputs == g @@@ inputs
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Answer (score 3):

```
f[l_List, r_Integer, q_Integer] := l[[Position[l, r][[1, 1]] + q]]

ll = {4, 1, 3, 8, 2, 7, 5, 10, 9, 6};

f[ll,5,3]
```

(* 6 *)

or obviously if you need both sides:

```
f[l_List, r_Integer, q_Integer] := {l[[Position[l, r][[1, 1]] + q]], 
  l[[Position[l, r][[1, 1]] - q]]}
```

Comment: This only returns the right side of the window.

Comment: Using the 'both sides' solution above: `f[{1, 2}, 1, 1]` evaluates to `{2, List}` which is wrong.

Comment: The OP answered your question above ("What result do you expect for [l1, 4, 4]"):  error because the left hand would fall out of the boundary of the list.  Read "Error" for "List"

Answer (score 3):

```
list = Range[8];
```

Pre-define `p` for better readability

```
p[x_] := Position[list, x][[1, 1]]
```

Using `Query` instead of `Part` to handle non-existing positions

```
f[list_, {a_, b_}] /; a > b := Query[p[a] + {-1, 1} b] @ list

f[list_, {a_, a_}] := {Query[p[a] + a] @ list}

f[__] := {}
```

Test it

```
f[list, {4, 3}]
```

{1, 7}

```
f[list, {4, 4}]
```

{8}

```
f[list, {4, 5}]
```

{}

Comment: You are treating the list as circular. Nice feature.

Answer (score 3):

```
inputs = {{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 4, 3}, 
         {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},  4, 4},
         {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 4, 5}, 
         {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4}, 4, 3},
         {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4}, 4, 7}, 
         {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -5, 7, 8, 4}, -5, 3}};
```

---

Grabbing the Nasser's example inputs and using `Extract`:

```
f[l_List, member_, d_Integer?Positive] := Module[{pos, tpos, pospm},
   pos = Flatten@Position[l, member];
   tpos = Thread[{pos + d, pos - d}];
   pospm = List /@ Flatten[Cases[#, n_ /; 0 < n <= Length@l] & /@ tpos];
   Extract[l, pospm]]

f @@@ inputs
```

---

*Results*:

> {{7, 1}, {8}, {}, {7, 1, 6}, {2}, {4, 3}}

Comparing with @kglr's function:

```
l = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4};

g[l, 4, 3] === f[l, 4, 3]

(*True*)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Using `Clip`:**

To filter neighbor indices that are less than one or greater the list length, `Clip` can be used.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SeedRandom[1];
list = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 20]

posNeighbor[k_List, item_, offset_] := Module[{
   len = Length@k
   , pos = Flatten@Position[k, item]
   },
  If[pos == {}, Return[pos]];
  h = ({# - offset, # + offset} & /@ pos) // 
    Map[Clip[#, {1, len}, {{}, {}}] &];
  k[[Flatten@h]]
  ]
```

---

Using @kglr's/@Nasser's test data:

```
inputs = {{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 4, 3}, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
     4, 4}, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 4, 
    5}, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4}, 4, 
    3}, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4}, 4, 
    7}, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -5, 7, 8, 4}, -5, 3}};


posNeighbor @@@ inputs
```

> {{1, 7}, {8}, {}, {1, 7, 6}, {2}, {3, 4}}

---

*Manipulate*

```
With[{list = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, 20]},
 Manipulate[
  Column[{
    list
    , posNeighbor[list, elem, offset]
    }]
  , {{elem, 1}, -2, 10, 1}
  , {{offset, 1}, 1, 8, 1}
  ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using list operations. Modify the error handling to suit your needs.

```
ClearAll@f;

f[list_List, value_, (distance_Integer)?Positive] := 
 Module[{pos = FirstPosition[list, value][[1]]},
  If[pos - distance < 1 || pos + distance > Length@list, Throw["Out of bounds"]];
  Extract[list, {{pos - distance}, {pos + distance}}] // Flatten]

l1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

f[l1, 4, 3]
(* {1, 7} *)

f[l1, 4, 1]
(* {3, 5} *)

f[l1, 4, 4]
(* "Uncaught Throw["Out of bounds"] returned to top level." *)
```

Comment: hi. This does not work for all cases. Try `f[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 4}, 4, 3]` it returns `{1,7}` but it should be `{1,7,6}` because there can be more than one element that match in the list. You only used the first one found.

Comment: the list should be flat so meeting this condition isn't crucial

Comment: @Nasser Actually according to @Ali that should return an error since there is no element to the right of the last `4`. Anyway, it is really simple to change my answer to use `Position` rather than `FirstPosition` to deal with duplicates.